# Livros de referência para estudar fonética e fonologia

Tags: discussion, recursos

Quero pedir recomendações de livros didáticos direcionados à aprendizagem da fonética e fonologia do português.

Prefiro obras que sejam consideradas de referência desde o nível de iniciado ao avançado.

Para manter as referências agrupadas são bem vindas recomendações de todas as variantes do português.

Comment: The following comparative reference ideas were given on main: *"Equivalent of books such as Phonetik Aktuell or Christopher Hall's Modern German Pronunciation for the German language. Or FSI's Introduction to French Phonology for the French language."* See [this thread](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/9355)